# Internal microphone with family 17h driver not works properly

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, amd-ryzen

OS: Ubuntu 22.04
Linux: 5.15.0-41-generic

1. When I use external microphone (earphone), the input is normal. And this is what I want.
   [image: Sound setting external mic]
2. When I use internal microphone, the input always in full bar.
   [image: Sound setting internal mic]
3. However when I adjust the volume to 30%, the sound is clear and not full bar.
   [image: internal hope]

It makes me uncomfortable with 100% of noise when I use 100% volume on internal mic. Usually even there is no noise reduction, the noise will not reach 100% bar.
How to fix this?

Comment: As far as I can see there's nothing to fix except maybe your external microphone that seems to have an extremely low input. The internal one seems to be working as expected.

Comment: @ChanganAuto No, I tested by using Windows the internal mic has similar sensitivity with the external mic.

Comment: So you're saying the external mic works better in Windows? And that matters because...?

Comment: I don't have problem with external mic (jack 3.5mm), it works well on Linux and windows. 
However the internal mic (built-in mic), the volume is too high until it doesn't recognize my voice. On another hand when I tested it on Windows the internal mic works well as external mic.